# Summing in dataframes by criteria

Tags: r, sum, mean, subset

I'm looking for a more efficient way to perform sum and mean calculations on data. I have a reasonably large dataframe (9 rows x 10^6 columns) consisting of measurements at different locations for a couple of years. I would like to calculate and plot sums and averages for different measurements at different timeframes for each station. I have around 3000 stations in my test dataset.

A truncated version of the data would be

```
Station DTG weight length
1  2010-2-15 01:00:00 7 54
2  2010-2-15 01:00:00 3 34
3  2010-2-15 01:00:00 6 51
...
1  2010-2-15 02:00:00 6 54
2  2010-2-15 02:00:00 9 73
3  2010-2-15 02:00:00 6 56
```

Where DTG is the date and time created using ISOdatetime.

I want to calculate the mean weight and length for each day (and month) for each station. I want to be able to find min and max as well. Plan is to put this into a dataframe so I can interrogate and plot.

My manual solution is to use subset and semi-manually do this. Obviously this isn't practical for the complete dataset.

I found one example for calculating daily rainfall data, but I couldn't get this to work nor see a way to extend to multiple stations.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope you mean 9 variables (columns) and a million records (rows), since this answer is aimed at that datasets.

To start with, you can coerce your character fields 'DTG' to date-time using `myData$DTG_ct <- as.POSIXct()` since this column is already in the default format, and you can create a regular array of time points like so:

```
 cutPoints <- as.POSIXct(outer(2000:2010,c('01',03,'07','10'),paste,'01 01:00:00 PST',sep = '-'))
 cutPointNames <- outer(outer(2000:2010,c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4')),paste)
```

Here I'm calculating quarter of year but you could easily create an array of months. To create an array of dates, use `as.Date(myData$DTG_ct)`

Then  you can use `cut()` to create an ordered factor that groups your data into time periods like so:

```
myData$DTG_quarter<-cut(x=myData$DTG_ct,
                       breaks=cutPoints,
                       labels=cutPointNames[-length(cutPOInts)])
# notice that cut() creates missing values before the first cutpoint 
# and after the last, and the labels are applied to data points that fall
# between cut points, so there needs to be one fewer labels than cut points.
```

then you can use `dplyr` to generate various statistics within time periods and with stations like so:

```
library(dplyr)
myData %>% 
    group_by(station,DTG_quarter) %>% 
    summarise(wt_mean=mean(weight),
              wt_sd=sd(weight),
              length_mean=mean(length),
              length_sd=mean(length))
```

For details on the above, read the Introduction to dplyr vignette , which can be found using `browseVignettes('dplyr')` after installing `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks @Jthorpe, I'll work through in detail to fully understand but this looks like what I was after.